# Roblox Studio Lua: Shop Screen Gui: Button Not showing

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a shop button, but it isn't showing when you hit the shop button. Here is a picture of what it looked like before changing the script:

[image: What it looks like before]

I want there to be a button there.

Now, the problem is probably in the children and parents. So here is a picture of the explorer:

[image: The Explorer]

And Finally Here is my changed script:

```
local frame = script.Parent
local FirstItemButton = script.Parent.Item1
local close = frame:WaitForChild("Close")
local shop = frame.Parent:WaitForChild("Shop")

shop.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()

shop.Visible = false
    frame.Visible = true
    FirstItemButton.Visible = true
end)

close.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    shop.Visible = true
    frame.Visible = false
    FirstItemButton.Visible = false
end)
```

The problem with this code is that the shop doesn't open AT ALL when the button is clicked. Please help, I've been stuck on this for days! Sorry to make this confusing for all of you with the pictures and the code, but please help. Thanks in advance! And also, if you want to see and play my game it is published, but it has a lot of bugs. Here is the link
https://web.roblox.com/games/1761867030/VIP-Battle-Simulator

Answer (score -1):

You can't use two mouse button clicks, you should only use one. If you use two, it might only run the first one.

This is a common mistake for most people.

Comment: This is not true. While it's usually unnecessary to have multiple connections to the same event, each connection is fired each time the event occurs. Further, the connections in this script are to different events, which obviously can both be listened to.

Comment: Sorry ChromaHQ but it the others are right. If they're not connected, why wouldn't it run the other?

Comment: Also, it works, it opens and closes it with the shop GUI the button just doesn't show

Answer (score -1):

It can only be put at the side or bottom or top of your screen

Answer (score -2):

First, I would like to say that `FirstItemButton` doesn't exist. `script.Parent.Item1` only exists in `script.Parent.ShopFrame.Item1` so you should fix that.

Secondly, I don't see a `shop` in your parent's children.

If you want to make things visible and unvisible, its better to just use a boolean variable and switch things around. For example:

```
local a = true
if a == true then
shop.Visible = false
frame.Visible = true
FirstItemButton.Visible = true
a = false
else
shop.Visible = true
frame.Visible = false
FirstItemButton.Visible = false
a = true
end
```

Comment: Um so I see what you are trying to say, the First part is correct, that fixes my not opening shop, but the button still doesn't show. And your second part, didn't work for me. If you can next time, can you just use my code, because I am a beginner at this Lua thing, and would like things to be as simple as it can be

Comment: The code on the bottom should be a good fix for you, just know where to edit it in and you should be all good to go!

Comment: Where should I place it in my script, and what should I delete? And reviewing your script, what about the close button?

Comment: You should know where to put it, just review my code and edit the stuff I said for you to edit. Place it where you know it'll work. Experiments never hurt.

Comment: I figured it out, it opens and closes properly now, but how can I make the button show this is driving me NUTS!!

Comment: `local frame = script.Parent
local FirstItemButton = script.Parent.ShopFrame.Item1
local close = frame:WaitForChild("Close")
local shop = frame.Parent:WaitForChild("Shop")

local a = false
 shop.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()

if a == false then
shop.Visible = false
frame.Visible = true
FirstItemButton.Visible = true
close.Visible = true
a = true
end
end)
close.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
if a == true then
shop.Visible = true
frame.Visible = false
FirstItemButton.Visible = false
close.Visible = false
a = false
end
end)





 
`